# Code after fscanf() doesn't execute

Tags: c, scanf

I am very new to C and have this simple code here:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){

    FILE *input = stdin;

    char string[20];
    while (fscanf(input, "%s",string)) {
        printf("String: %s \n",string);
    }
    printf("Done");

    return 0;
}
```

The problem I am having is that the the "Done" line never gets printed. When the while loop is finished reading from the stdin, it doesn't execute anything after it. Is there some concept that I am not aware of? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could have a buffer overflow. Make sure you are typing less than 19 characters into your prompt (or expand the size of string[20])

Comment: This is not sufficient, please post portions of the input file.

Comment: Does char string[20] not mean that each so called string is not allocated 20 characters? I have entered just a single word under 20 characters and the printf after the loop still doesn't get executed.

Comment: @iharob, there is no input file, it's all stdin

Comment: Oh, why didn't you use `scanf()`?

Comment: "When the while loop is finished reading from the stdin" - has it actually finished reading from stdin? How have you terminated stdin?

Comment: @iharob If i use scanf(), it doesn't allow me to type anything on the command line, it goes straight to the done printf statement

Comment: how do you know it finished the loop? if it does not print "done" it is most likely because it is stuck in the loop...  your expression might be wrong.. you should add a null terminator otherwise it will keep reading, something like `while ( fscanf(input, "%s",string) =! NULL )) {} `

Comment: @davmac I am a little confused on what you are asking. I am a complete beginner in C. Doesn't the while loop tell the program when it is done reading from stdin?

Comment: @dhint4 the while loop says to do something while a condition is true. In this case, it will keep reading from stdin as long as it is able to match input. What I'm asking is, how are you signalling that there is no more input available? As others have hinted, you normally need to press ctrl+D or similar to signal that you have no more 'stdin' input.

Comment: @bakriawad: `fscanf()` returns `EOF` at the end of input (or on error), not `NULL`.  Also, `=! NULL` is not valid C (or C++).

Comment: @davmac, I have tried using while != EOF and it still doesn't break down to the printf statement. I understand what you are asking.

Comment: @frasnian thanks, i am not a C programmer, not yet atleast, if so then is the data displayed correctly? are there errors? does the program exit straight away? try adding getch() after printing "Done".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change it to look for `EOF`:

```
while (EOF != fscanf(input, "%s",string)) {
```

The `EOF` character is `^Z` in Windows or `^D` in *nix (i.e. Ctrl+Z or Ctrl+D).  After entering the EOF character, you still have to hit enter because keyboard input will be line buffered.

Comment: thanks for your response but I just tried this and the done printf statement is still not executed.

Comment: @dhint4 be aware that by "^D" frasnian means "hold control and press D".

Comment: @davmac, if I press Crtl-D, the printf statement executes but I want this to be done automatically, how come the EOF in my while loops doesn't do this?

Comment: @dhint4: what do you mean by: "but I want this to be done automatically, how come the EOF in my while loops doesn't do this"?

Comment: @fransnian, if I have the while(scanf != EOF), shouldn't the Ctrl+D be automatically executed? I shouldn't have to tell the while loop that the scanf is done reading from the file, isn't this the purpose of EOF?

Comment: @dhint4: If you have `fscanf(input, "%s",string)) `, what you are saying is "read from file 'input' until either the end of file is encountered or a string is entered.  If a string is entered, put it in a buffer pointed to by 'string'."  By putting that in your while statement (e.g. `while (EOF != fscanf(...))  `), you are saying "while an end-of-file is not encountered, do this again".  As noted in my answer, keyboard input is line-buffered.  This means you have to press "Enter" before your input is processed.  This is why inside the loop `printf` won't get called until after you press enter.

Comment: @frasnian, here is an example I would type: 

"This is a test message:

I would then press enter. The printf will not execute after this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69514/discussion-between-frasnian-and-dhint4).

Comment: Minor: A more idiomatic approach would be `while (1 == fscanf(input, "%s",string)) {`.  IOW: if the input is not as expected, then stop.  Of course this make no difference as `fscanf(input, "%s",string)` will not return 0, but had the format been something more interesting like `fscanf(input, "%d", &i)`, continuing with `== 1` make more sense than continuing at `!= EOF`.

Comment: @chux: good point.  Also, if OP enters "This is a test^D" (or ^Z on Windows), the `%s` format specifier will eat the `EOF`.  (but I think OP has his/her hands full enough at the moment) ^D.

Comment: @dhint4: adding as comment as you did not move to chat:  


Enter: "This is a test message" Now press Enter 
Your program should print "This is a test message" 
If you are using Windows, Enter: Ctrl+Z Now press Enter 
OR If your are using Linux, Enter: Ctrl+D Now press Enter 
Your program should print "Done"

Comment: @dhint4: In addition, the last line of output is not guaranteed to appear on `stdout` unless it ends with a newline character. You should use `printf ("Done\n");` or `puts ("Done");`.

Comment: @NisseEngström: You're just going to freak OP out - when the program terminates the buffer will be flushed, and the last statement in the application is the `printf` call.

Comment: @frasnian: I should have written "not guaranteed to be printed". It will be written to `stdout` of course.